# Maya right click context sensitive menu

Tags: python, contextmenu, menuitem, maya, right-click

I am trying to edit the right click context sensitive menu from Maya. I have found how to add a menuItem but I would like to have this Item in the top of the list not at the bottom... I think in this case I need to deleteAllItems from the menu, add mine and then re-add the default Maya ones but I don't know how to re-add them. Where can I find it ?  Most of the topics say "modify Maya's source code" but that's not even an option.

Any suggestions ?

Thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i think I have found a solution, that's the best I have found but this is not very handy...

create a copy of the **buildobjectMenuItemsNow.mel** and **dagMenuProc.mel** in your script folder so Maya will read those ones instead of the native ones. Once you have done that you can modify the **dagMenuProc.mel** without destructing anything as you re working on a copy.
the proc that needs modifications is the last one : ***dagMenuProc*** (line 2240)

and you can start modifying inside the loop (line 2266)

What I have done is make a call to a Python file that adds some more items in the menu and you can obviously remove some items by deleting few MEL lines.

I hope this can help someone.
And if there is an other way of doing that, I would love to hear about !